# SwiftyDropbox setup with Carthage

Tags: swift, dropbox-api, carthage, swiftydropbox

I'm following the steps to install SwiftyDropbox using Carthage. My Cartfile is:

```
# SwiftyDropbox
github "https://github.com/dropbox/SwiftyDropbox" ~> 5.1.0
```

When I run "carthage update --platform iOS" I get:

```
third_party (master) $ carthage update --platform iOS
*** Fetching SwiftyDropbox
*** Fetching Alamofire
*** Checking out Alamofire at "4.9.1"
*** Checking out SwiftyDropbox at "5.1.0"
*** xcodebuild output can be found in /var/folders/gk/1sxbjcg969d6k1lc945cvz2m0000gn/T/carthage-xcodebuild.jD6xnh.log
*** Building scheme "Alamofire iOS" in Alamofire.xcworkspace
Failed to write to /.../third_party/Carthage/Build/iOS/Alamofire.framework: Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=260 "The file “Alamofire.framework” couldn’t be opened because there is no such file." UserInfo={NSURL=file:///.../third_party/Carthage/Checkouts/Alamofire/build/ArchiveIntermediates/Alamofire%20iOS/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/Alamofire.framework, NSFilePath=/.../third_party/Carthage/Checkouts/Alamofire/build/ArchiveIntermediates/Alamofire iOS/BuildProductsPath/Release-iphoneos/Alamofire.framework, NSUnderlyingError=0x7f92c9407d60 {Error Domain=NSPOSIXErrorDomain Code=2 "No such file or directory"}}
```

I see there is a difference in the paths, where the UserInfo path has an escape character: Alamofire%20iOS while the NSFilePath doesn't (Alamofire iOS). I'm using macOS 10.15.2, Xcode 11.3, carthage 0.34.0. Why is the escape character there and how can I fix it?

Comment: Have you tried to delete the Carthage directory and run `carthage update --platform iOS` again?